# Copying Attachments from One List to Another

Tags: designer-workflow, attachments

I am currently using the Create an Item action in SharePoint Designer 2013 to bring over several fields of information from my main list to another.
Is it possible to copy over the attachment associated with the item?
I can see the "Attachments" field in my main list, but not the other.

Is this something I can do OOTB, or would it require something custom?

Comment: Is there any way of implementing the same using Sharepoint 2013 workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint 2010 workflow to copy list items from one list to other list with attachment.

Here is the workflow:

If Current Item:Status equals Yes
    Copy item in Current Item to N2
    Set workflow status to Moved
    Delete item in Current Item

Here i am copying list items from N1 List to N2 list.
Its works fine.